# Comparing integers in a certain block Sudoku Java

Tags: java, sudoku

So i've update my code and im still stumped on how to check a 3x3 block within a completed sudoku board to see if it doesn't have any repeating numbers. this is my method that i've updated.

```
static boolean isBlock1Valid(int[][] sudokuBoard, int referenceRow, int referenceColumn)
{

    boolean[] seen = new boolean[9];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){

            if ( seen(sudokuBoard[referenceColumn+i][referenceRow+j])) return false;


    else ( seen(sudokuBoard[referenceColumn+i][referenceRow+j])) = true;
    }
    }
return true;
}//end of isBlock1Valid
```

this  is the calling method i don't know which parametrs to send to the method isBlock1Valid

```
    public static void Validate(final int[][] sudokuBoard)
{
    int width = sudokuBoard[0].length;
    int height = sudokuBoard.length;

    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        if(!IsValidRow(sudokuBoard, i, width))
        {
            System.out.print("Invalid entry found \n (Row)" + "\t"+ i + "\n");
          //Do something - The row has repetitions
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("Row " +i + " is valid \n");
        }
    for(int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        if(!IsValidColumn(sudokuBoard, j, height))
        {
            System.out.print("(Column)" + j + "\n");
          //Do something - The columns has repetitions
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("Column " +j +" is valid \n");
        }
   for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
        if(!IsBlock1Valid(sudokuBoard,i, j)){
            System.out.print("hi");
        }

}
```

Comment: So.. what's wrong with that code? Does it fail? For which inputs?

Comment: I believe this code won't compile... :D

Comment: No it isn't compiling.. im unsure if im using the `boolean[] seen` correctly to check the reference column and row.

Comment: Okay, what's the compiler error message you get? On which line of your code?

Comment: when i call the method. I don't which parameters to send it. ill update the question with the  calling method i have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing a cell in an array should be using square brackets, and `seen` is an array:

```
seen[sudokuBoard[referenceColumn+i][referenceRow+j]]
```

Comment: That seems to clear out all the error messages for the method. thanks so much